# Why does peak torque increase on increasing air gap in induction motor?

Tags: motor, three-phase, induction-motor, electric-machine, magnetic-flux

I have been trying for a while to summarize the effects of increasing air gap in an induction motor with constant load. I understand that increasing air gap with constant supply voltage demands high magnetezing current for the same magnetic flux, and this also causes reduction in power factor. But I also found that maximum torque or breakdown torque also increases on increasing air gap. However, an increase in air gap should also cause increase in leakage reactance, to which the maximum torque is inversely proportional. Hence its value should decrease but the opposite happens. So, what is happening here?

Comment: Only saturation effects shud do that

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Where are you learning what increasing air gap does? Link to the textbook or teaching materials please, in case there is some important context missing.

Comment: Magnetic core saturation reduces L and H thus torque so in that region, where reducing saturation at a slightly lower current so if a bigger air gap increases L faster than the H reduction from I, it might increase torque due to saturation effects. But Remanence is a key factor so degaussing is assumed.

Comment: I am mostly using Google and YouTube because I couldn't find it in my textbook (Dr. P.S Bimbhra, Electrical Machinery). Here are some of the links :  https://www.electricalvolt.com/2019/01/effects-of-air-gap-on-the-performance-of-induction-motor/       https://www.engineeringexchange.com/m/blogpost?id=2316460%3ABlogPost%3A446505

Comment: One of those sources says nothing about the effect on torque; the other (as I would expect) directly contradicts the premise of the question.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/447539/why-is-the-air-gap-between-the-stator-and-rotor-on-a-motor-kept-as-small-as-it-i?rq=1  According to the first comment in this answer, peak torque gets increased on increasing air gap. Also, I thought that in the first link I mentioned in my previous comment says that overload capacity increases, which should be peak torque? The second source mentioned reduction in magnetic flux, but I thought it was a function of supply voltage and should remain constant? Overall, I am too confused on various aspects of increasing air gap.